# SQLite-Net populate ListView partially

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, uwp, sqlite-net-extensions

I'm using [SQLite-Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) to read and write data to a local `SQLite` database. On one page of my app I need all entries from a specific table that match a query. I also need to retrieve the child entities with relationships to the parent model. Therefore I use [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/overview). Fetching the items on a mobile device can take some time.

As the `ListView` can't show all entries anyway - I want to load i.e. the first 100 entries and than all the rest when the user scrolls the `ListView`.

I wrote a `DatabaseHelper` which provides the following method:

```
public async static Task<ObservableCollection<Item>> GetItemsByQueryAsync(string query)
{
    List<Item> models = null;
    var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() => getAsyncSQLiteConnection());
    models = await conn.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<Item>(i => i.name.Contains(query));
    return new ObservableCollection<Item>(models);
}
```

I call this method from my `ViewModel` to create the `ItemsSource` for the `ListView`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items

private async void GetItems()
{
    Items = await DatabaseHelper.GetItemsByQueryAsync(SearchQuery);
}
```

This is the XAML code for the `ListView` (I removed the template code)

```
<ListView x:Name="Items_ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is implementing the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface that is build in the framework ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701916 )

A good example can be found here:
https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/

Comment: Followed the example! Working great - Thank you